# Is it possible for slave devices to initiate communication with master - main processor in i2c protocol?

Tags: i2c

Can a device connected to main processor can initiate a i2c communication.
For example, FAN connected using i2c bus, is it possible for a FAN to send a feedback to main processor.

Answer (score 0):

Common solution to a problem like this is to have a separate interrupt line.

I3C supports in-band interrupts, if you're not set on I2C yet.